# Expression.Block different signatures change parameters values to null

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-core

I am trying to implement a method that builds a `Func<,>` dynamically, depending on what types are provided. 
The `Func` itself is supposed to simply call a static method and return its first parameter. I have a few dummy classes:

```
public class Foo { }
public class Foo1 : Foo { }
public class Foo2 : Foo { }
public class Foo3 : Foo { }
```

And the usage of method looks like this:

```
var genericTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(Foo1), typeof(Foo2), typeof(Foo3) };
var func = BuildFunc(genericTypes);
var res = func.DynamicInvoke(new Foo1(), new Foo2(), new Foo3());
```

When I was proptotyping it was working fine. However when I tried to implement it properly I encountered a strange behaviour which I can't explain.

Here is how I implemented the method:

```
private static Delegate BuildFunc(List<Type> genericTypes)
{
    List<ParameterExpression> parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
    for (int i = 0; i < genericTypes.Count; i++)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(genericTypes[i], "arg" + i);
        parameters.Add(param);
    }

    var methodCallInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Single(a => a.Name == "PopulateChildren");
    var parameterArray = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(Foo), parameters);

    var callExpr = Expression.Call(methodCallInfo,
        parameterArray);

    //return arg0
    LabelTarget returnTarget = Expression.Label(type: parameters[0].Type);
    GotoExpression returnExpression = Expression.Return(returnTarget,
        parameters[0], parameters[0].Type);
    var returnLabel = Expression.Label(returnTarget, parameters[0]);


    //assembling & compiling
    var assembled = Expression.Block(
            parameters,
            callExpr,
            returnExpression,
            returnLabel);

    var compiled = Expression.Lambda(assembled, parameters).Compile();
    return compiled;
}

public static void PopulateChildren(Foo[] objects)
{

}
```

As you can see the code above defines parameters, initializes an array with parameters, makes a call to a method and returns its first parameter.

Now if you run this code and step throught `PopulateChildren` method - you will get `objects` collection with 3 null values.

And if you change

```
    var assembled = Expression.Block(
        parameters,
        callExpr,
        returnExpression,
        returnLabel);
```

to

```
    var assembled = Expression.Block(
        parameters[0],
        parameters[1],
        parameters[2],
        callExpr,
        returnExpression,
        returnLabel);
```

you will get values! 
Now I discovered that different signatures of `Expression.Block` contain either `has no variables` or `that contains the given variables` words in its summary.

I found signatures for this method overloads here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.block(v=vs.100).aspx and I thought to myself: "Ok, I'm just stupid and accidently used a wrong signature. I will use a right one!"

So I chose this one:
`Block(IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>, IEnumerable<Expression>)` which has a description `Creates a BlockExpression that contains the given variables and expressions.`

So I changed the abovesaid code to

```
        var expresssion = new List<Expression>()
        {
            callExpr,
            returnExpression,
            returnLabel
        };
        var assembled = Expression.Block(parameters, expresssion);
```

And it still gives me null values!

Can someone please explain to me what is going on and what I am missing?
And most importantly how do I call `Expression.Block` in a way that accepts a collection of parameters and doesn't turn them to null?

**Clarification**

This whole idea is born due to trying build an ORM around Dapper. 
Dapper allows multipmapping https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multi-mapping

The way its used is

```
    var sql = 
    @"select * from #Posts p 
    left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId 
    Order by p.Id";

    var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;});
```

The great part is that you can get hierarchy of objects in one trip to the database. The part that I dislike is that you have to specify types as generic arguments. I see that it is needed, but I would like to take a step further and provide a way to simply call `GetWithChildren<User>(id)` and receive `User` with populated `Post` children. So in order to do that I have to do following:

1. Build a tree of dependent children types (tables) relationship
2. Build a sql query that will select them
3. Construct a Func<> that populates children/parent relationship
4. Make a call to correct Query<> method and passing a Func

Basically I am almost there, the only issue that I have is described above
My Func<> is supposed to simply call a method that does a hard work.

Comment: Can you write a short sample of how you want to use the code? it strikes me that there may be a simpler way of doing what you're describing without going down through several layers of reflection and expressions

Comment: @DiskJunky I can but I am not sure it will help. I have a 3rd party library that exposes generic methods, each of them accept a func with generic arguments, so like `void Foo<T1,T2>(Func<T1,T2> func)` and `void Foo<T1,T2,T3>(Func<T1,T2,T3> func)` etc. I am trying to be able to call these methods dynamically.

Comment: @DiskJunky in real life I won't be invoking a Func, it will be invoked by 3rd party library

Comment: It helps in that by seeing the intended usage, there may be a different and simpler approach to take. I'm struggling to see why you'd want to do such a thing. Dynamic invocation should be avoided if possible

Comment: @DiskJunky I've updated the question with a clarification of what I am trying to archieve. To be honest at this point it's not as much about getting it to work as it is about the question why it doesn't

Comment: In all honesty I think the reason why you're getting `null`s back is because you're getting tangled in the lambda recursive nature in what you're doing - it's unweildy and unmaintainable for anyone else, even yourself if you come back to change it. If you want to cleanly separate out concerns for reach request, handler and response then the Mediator pattern is the way to go. It's not generic or flashy but it silos your code vertically and will be considerably more maintainable. Sometimes the best solution is the plain, straight way through, not the convoluted path that people can't follow